# How can I set up the progress of seekBar according to a number?

Tags: kotlin, seekbar

I would like to set up the progress of the seekBar according to a provided number in Detail/Update fragment

```
private fun setSeekBar() {
    binding.seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(object : SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {
        override fun onProgressChanged(seekBar: SeekBar?, progress: Int, fromUser: Boolean) {

            binding.numberUpdateSeekBar.text = getString(R.string.seek_bar_result, progress)
            binding.seekBar ...//I would like to have the seek bar adjusted to the number

        }

        override fun onStartTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) {
        }

        override fun onStopTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) {
        }
    })
}
```

The number itself is passed correctly but the seekBar's progress isn't set to the number.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can set progress of a seekbar like this way.

```
seekbar.setProgress(progressValue)
```

In progressValue you have to pass value of progress to seekbar.

At first you have to set max value for seekbar like this way

```
seekbar.setMax(maxValue)
```

In maxValue you have to pass value of maximum progress to seekbar.

Comment: Hi, somehow it doesn't work but thanks for your answer :)

Comment: Can u share some code where u have implemented?

Comment: Hi, thanks you for trying to help! and sorry about the delayed response. I am quite a noobie and I don't know how to fix it. I tried several things but without success